# Not redirect htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a simple .htaccess rule, I am trying to redirect

`http://example.com/pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/feed/  to http://example.com/page.php?url=pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/feed/`

my .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ page.php?url=$1
```

But it shows 404 error
'The requested URL /pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/feed/ was not found on this server.'
Any one please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Because `pittsburgh.cbslocal.com` has `.` in it, so the regex `^([^.]+)$` won't match it.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?url=$1
```